# Transactions end while other transaction is being executed

Tags: java, transactions, seam

I am using JBoss Seam and working with transactions.
I have 2 methods with the @Transactional annotation.

```
@Transactional
public void method1()
{
   ...
   entityManager.flush();
}

@Transactional
public void method2()
{
   ...
   entityManager.flush();
}
```

My problem is that if method1 and method2 are being executed at the same time and method1 ends the transaction, then there will not be any running transactions for method2.
How can I solve this? Can I force a transaction to be always active while there is code running on the method, even using manual flushing?

Comment: What do you mean with "same time"? Do you mean 1 thread is executing method1, another is executing method2, and both action should be in one transaction??

Comment: One thread is on method1, other on method2 and if the transaction ends on method1 it should work ok on method2

Comment: I see. JBoss supports multithreaded transactions, but I've never used it personally...

Comment: I have already solved it removing the manual flushes... thx anyway.

Comment: Good to know. Post your own answer and mark it as accepted two days from now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a little bit late to answer... but it should do... :)

I just removed all the manual flushes from the code and let Seam take care of the transactions... and it workes as I wished.